# Determine if z is a function of x and y. $6x-4y+2z=10$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

"Determine if z is a function of x and y. $6x-4y+2z=10$. Find the formula"

All i did was equate for z
$$z = 5-3x+2y$$

That is the formula. And It's pretty obvious that the answers are unique but i don't really understand how to provide or as the question says "determine" it is a function x and y. I can't find it in the notes either.

Comment: It's hard to say what they want when they give no domain whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

My answer...

Now in order for z to be a function of x and y points must uniquely satsify the equation for example in function $x^4+y^4+z^4=16$
$$f(0,0,2)=f(0,0,-2)$$
Meaning more than one point satisfy the equation.

Where as for the given function we can solve for itself uniquely given that we know (x,y).
$$6x-4y+2z=10$$ $$z=5-3x+2y$$

Comment: The problem with that answer (which I suspect is acceptable) is that you never "determined" that $z = f(x, y)$ _was_ a function--you merely stated that it was: _"...the given function...[is]...uniquely given [if] we know $(x,y)$."_  Which is equivalent to saying "the given function satisfies the definition of a function."  But the problem with an "actual" answer is that I don't see that it has to do with calculus at all--functions for sure but those types of proofs would be more appropriate in a discrete mathematics or real analysis class, I would think.

Comment: I mentioned they gave no domain.  How would you answer the question if I told you that $x$ and $y$ range over the complex values and $z$ ranges over the real values?  You then solve $z = 5 - 3x + 2y$?  What is the domain of this function which you claim _definitely_ exists?  $x$ and $y$ can take on complex values, so is the domain $\mathbb{C}$?  Think about it...the answer is definitely no.  There is a surface in the 2D complex plane where $-3\Im(x) + 2\Im(y) = 0$ which always (essentially) gives a "trivial" $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ function (which is the one you found).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment about differing domains:

> How would you answer the question if I told you that x and y range over the complex values and z ranges over the real values?

We know right away that if $z$ is a real value that $3x$ and $-2y$ *must* be conjugates of each other...specifically:

$$
\Im \Big(3x - 2y = 3\Re(x) - 2\Re(y) + 3\Im(x) - 2\Im(y)\Big) = 0
$$

Thus $3\Im(x) - 2\Im(y) = 0$.  Now let's simplify the notation a bit: $x = r_x + ix$ and $ y = r_y + iy$ such that $\Re(x) = r_x$, $\Re(y) = r_y$, $\Im(x) = x$, and $\Im(y) = y$.  We *now* find that $3\Im(x) - 2\Im(y) = 0 \rightarrow 3x - 2y = 0 \rightarrow y = \frac{3x}{2}$:

$$
3x - 2y = 3r_x - 2r_y
$$

Which finally leads us to:

$$
z = 5 - 3r_x + 2r_y
$$

This means that for *every* imaginary number you can think of (including $0$--i.e. all reals), there are two independent sets of real values satisfying your original function $z = 5 - 3r_x + 2r_y$ where the "first" ("$x$") real value has imaginary value of $x$ and the "second" ("$y$") an imaginary value of $\frac{3x}{2}$.

It's tricky to nail down the full domain because the domain hits every $x \in \mathbb{C}$ *and* every $y \in \mathbb{C}$ *but not* every $x$ *combined with* every $y$ (i.e. it is easy to find a combination of $\{x, y\} \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that the value of $5 - 3x + 2y$ is *not* real and thus *not* in the domain of the function:

$$
z = f(x, y): \left(\mathrm{D}\subset\mathbb{C}\right) \mapsto \mathbb{R}
$$